# How to when I click on the cell to perform a specific work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell

I want create one page tableview and I want when to click on any cell perform a specific work!

(for example when I to click cell receive NSString value from a specific URL address)

this is a piece of my code:

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tables;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *Number2 = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.104/janatan/filemanager.php?dir=root&foldernum"]];
     folderNumber = [Number2 integerValue];

    for (int i=0; i < folderNumber; i++)
    {
        NSString *folderName = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.104/janatan/filemanager.php?dir=root&folder=%d&name",i]]];
        if (!folder)
        {
            folder = [NSMutableArray array];
        }
        [folder addObject:folderName];
    }
    all = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [all addObjectsFromArray:folder];



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([folder containsObject:[all objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue2" sender:self];
    }
    //I want when to click any cell get NSString from this URL:
    //"http://192.168.1.104/janatan/filemanager.php?dir=root&**folder=%d**&id"
    //(this URL give me id for any folder and any folder is in any cell)
}
```

Comment: Use NSURLConnection or third-party library (e.g. AFNetworking) to connect to server. Do you want to somebody show how make internet connection?

Comment: yes I do . please tell me more

Answer (score 0):

you can download string from URL using following code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your URL to Download String"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *err = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Response : %@", responseString);
```